# Servicenow integration with SAP

Tags: rest, servicenow

I’m a new ServiceNow Administrator/Developer and a client ask me to develop a solution to integrate the ServiceNow data with SAP or vice versa.

And I have the following concerns:

1. How can I get an instance in SAP to develop on it and start with the API integration?
2. ServiceNow is a cloud base service and I think that the SAP it’s a desktop software and it start to integrate it on the cloud, right?
3. I'm thinking of use the REST API of ServiceNow to send and receive the data, it’s there any other workaround just to be aware?

Note: I'm not an expert a just been in ServiceNow for like 3 months so if you have any tip that could help me in the future I will be grateful to hear it.

Comment: SAP is a huge software company, hundreds of software. So asking "I think that the SAP it’s a desktop software [...], right?" can be answered only by you. Please tell us which SAP software it is!

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to SAP, I would suggest, pushing the data from SAP to SNow via a Scripted Rest Endpoint.  If you have something like SAP PI, you can have it send the JSON data then parse it out to a staging table in SNow then run your transform from there. SAP is very protective of its data, and life is just easier pushing it out from SAP, instead of trying to pull it in from SNow.

Answer (score 0):

enosix (https://enosix.com/) has a cloud-accessible, REST API wrapper for on-premise SAP ECC instances.  You could use that to get data into and out of SAP by calling the API from SNow.